# Extra argument method in call

Tags: swift3, xcode8, alamofire

Why this alamofire method showing the error?
Have anybody fixed it?

```
Alamofire.request(baseURL, method: .get, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in 

print(response.request as Any)

}
```

[image]

Comment: past your code not screenshots and similar questions you read

Comment: I have updated the code, pls check now.

Comment: everything seems fine to me. Have you tried actually running the project? Xcode is buggy at some times...

Comment: @SatishMavani Why are you making request in `prepareforsegue` when you receive response in completionHandler before that your segue is performed.

Comment: @NiravD this is not a solution, even if i write it out of prepareforsegue it gives me same error.

Comment: @SatishMavani I have never told that it is solution, What I have mentioned is `prepareforsegue` is not a good place to make API call.

Comment: @NiravD Ok thanks for that suggestion. Do you have any solution for query?

Comment: @SatishMavani Show the declaration of `param`.

Comment: i have declared param like this:  var param = ["username" : "support@motifworks.com", "password" : "Support@!234"]

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with  Alamofire version 4.4.0.0.

Comment: @andy7586  kindly upvote the question instead of just making a comment, so that other people can help...

Comment: @Mady  kindly upvote the question instead of just making a comment, so that other people can help...